# I cant see the element of a TableView - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, element

I have this problem, when a run my application I Cant see the elements Than I before added to my table, I create a Class (Personas) and use the PropertyValueFactory. thanks and sorry for the error in the language, I speak Spanish. This is the code:

```
package ejemplo.tableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class EjemploTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Personas> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Personas("Diego","Maradona"),
                new Personas("Lionel","Messi")

        );
        TableView<Personas> tabla = new TableView();

        TableColumn<Personas,String> c1 = new TableColumn("Nombre");
        c1.setMinWidth(200d);
        c1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Personas,String>("nombre"));

        TableColumn<Personas,String> c2 = new TableColumn("Apellido");
        c2.setMinWidth(200d);
        c2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("apellido"));

        tabla.getColumns().addAll(c1,c2);
        tabla.setItems(data);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().add(tabla);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

this is the class Personas:

```
package ejemplo.tableview;

public class Personas {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    public Personas(String nombre,String apellido){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `Personas`. I guess the problem will be the missing accessors of that class. It shall have a public `nombreProperty()` or `getNombre()` and a public `apellidoProperty()` or `getApellido()` with String return type.

Comment: Ok, I post the code, Sorry again, Im new in this page.

Comment: do you think than I have to create two getter methods than return the name(nombre) and the surname(apellido)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation of [PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> A convenience implementation of the Callback interface, designed
>   specifically for use within the TableColumn cell value factory. An
>   example of how to use this class is:
>
> TableColumn firstNameCol = new
>   TableColumn("First Name"); 
>   firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new
>   PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
>
> In this example, the **"firstName" string is used as a reference to an
>   assumed firstNameProperty() method** in the Person class type (which is
>   the class type of the TableView items list). Additionally, **this method
>   must return a Property instance**. If a method meeting these
>   requirements is found, then the TableCell is populated with this
>   ObservableValue. In addition, the TableView will automatically add an
>   observer to the returned value, such that any changes fired will be
>   observed by the TableView, resulting in the cell immediately updating.
>
> **If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through
>   support for attempting to call get() or is() (that
>   is, getFirstName() or isFirstName() in the example above)**. If a method
>   matching this pattern exists, the value returned from this method is
>   wrapped in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper and returned to the TableCell.
>   However, in this situation, this means that the TableCell will not be
>   able to observe the ObservableValue for changes (as is the case in the
>   first approach above).

Based on this the modified `Personas` class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Personas {
    private StringProperty nombre = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty apellido = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty nombreProperty() {return nombre;};
    public StringProperty apellidoProperty() {return apellido;};

    public Personas(String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.nombre.set(nombre);
        this.apellido.set(apellido);
    }

    public String getNombre() {return nombre.get();}
    public String getApellido() {return apellido.get();}
}
```